# How to instance an ImageView from a class?

Tags: android

Sorry for bugging you again, but how do I instance an ImageView ( or any other layout element ) from a class?

For example, in Activity I can simply write **ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);** , but what should I place instead of "this" if I'm instancing it from a class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually you'd place your view in an activity, right?

So you could pass the Activity instance as an object when creating the view.

```
class YourClass {

 void createView(Activity activity) {

         ImageView iv = new ImageView(activity);



  }  }
```

Comment: Right... only one problem, I can't access this objects from other methods of the same class.

Comment: I think you make your imageView (iv) object as an instance variable so that it can be accessed from other methods of your class